# How to allocate objects without saving them in variables?

Tags: java

In my Java book there is an exercise that ask you to : "Allocate 10000 Rational objects without saving them in variables to they become garbage."

Is below the correct way to allocate objects without assigning them to varaibles?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        new Rational();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You have a strange book.

Comment: Well... 10 000 objects? Check. Are they Rational? Check. Allocated them? Check. Not assigned them? Check. Looks to me you completed the task correctly. But I do agree with @ChristianMann - your book is not a Rational object :-)

Comment: What is the title/author of the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, each `Rational` is instantiated without a reference and therefore are subsequently garbage collected at some point.  Java doesn't have a way to force garbage collection, but you can call `Runtime.gc()` to request a garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

True, provided the constructor doesn't have side effects such as retaining a reference.

```
class Rational {
    static final List<Rational> IRRATIONAL = new ArrayList<Rational>();

    Rational() {
        IRRATIONAL.add(this);
    }

    static Iterable<Rational> allRationals() {
        return IRRATIONAL;
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    new Rational();
}

for(Rational r: Rational.allRationals()) {
    // all still here
}
```